# Selecting Form Values OnChange

Tags: jquery

I have a large form with many inputs (form can have more than 100 values) and this seems to be causing some instability when posting back to the server using `jquery.serialize()`.

Often, only one or two values are changed before the form is submitted, so I thought I try submitting just the values that changed. Only I'm not sure how to do that.

I think I want to select all inputs on the form and call `jquery.change()` on them, then somehow use the `eventData` to determine which values it is that changed.

Any assistance with the code, or alternate ideas on how I might go about this would be appreciated.

---

I suppose I should have mentioned, it's MVC-4.

Here's the script I've come up with so far.

> ```
> $(document).ready(function () {
>     $("#EditForm").find("input")
>         .on("change", function (event)
>         {
>             var name = this.name;
>             var value = this.value;
>
>             var form = {};
>             form[name] = value;
>
>             $.post("/Contracts/EditSingle", form, function (data)
>             {
>                 $("#editContractResponse").html(data);
>             });
>     });
> });
> ```

This works, but it posts on every input edit. I like the idea about finding out which inputs are dirty, but not sure how to bring that about.

Comment: if you will store the data into a database you could use JSON to send it to the code behind. Then again if you do that, you will have to make sure a lot of fields can be null. This will have as result that you will have invalid/incomplete data entries. Are you using just jQuery or using anything for your code behind?

Comment: please post the code as you have managed to so  far.

Comment: Couldn't you capture the onChange event and set a property in the form field like isDirty, then when submitting your form check which fields have this property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like the following. All we do when an element is changed is add that element to an array. When the form is submitted, we serialize only the elements in that array, and POST them.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var els = [];

    // This uses event delegation, as it's more optimal for attaching handlers to multiple elements
    $('#EditForm').on('change', 'input,select,textarea', function () {
        els.push(this);
    }).on('submit', function (e) {
        // Prevent the default action (form submission) occuring, so we can AJAX instead.
        e.preventDefault();



        jQuery.post('/Contacts/Edit', $(jQuery.unique(els)).serialize(), function (data) {
            $('#editContractResponse').html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

[`jQuery.unique()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique) removes duplicate DOM elements from the array (incase the same element is altered again and again). You could check for this inside the `change` handler instead if you preferred. `jQuery.unique()` returns the array of unique element, which we build a jQuery object from, and serialize the result.